# Did the prophet prefer to give government positions to those who didn’t seek them?

Tags: source-identification, reference-request

I recall reading a hadith which said as much but I can’t remember the wording of it. I tried searching keywords on sunnah . Com but didn’t have any luck.

If you know such a Hadith please tell me it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the following ahadith are relevant:

> عن أبي موسى، قال دخلت على النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم أنا ورجلان من بني عمي فقال أحد الرجلين يا رسول الله أمرنا على بعض ما ولاك الله عز وجل ‏.‏ وقال الآخر مثل ذلك فقال ‏ إنا والله لا نولي على هذا العمل أحدا سأله ولا أحدا حرص عليه
>
> Abu Musa said: "I entered upon the Prophet (ﷺ) along with two of my paternal cousins.
>
> One of the two men said: 'O Messenger of Allah appoint me over some of that with which Allah has entrusted you,' and the other one said something similar.
>
> He said: 'By Allah, we will not appoint to such positions anyone who asks for it , or anyone who is eager for it.'
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1733c)</sup>

> لن أو لا نستعمل على عملنا من أراده
>
> We will never appoint to this work those who want it.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2261) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1733d)</sup>

> لا تسأل الإمارة، فإنك إن أوتيتها عن مسألة وكلت إليها، وإن أوتيتها من غير مسألة أعنت عليها
>
> Do not seek a position of authority, for if you are given it when you ask for it, you will be left alone (without divine support), but if you are given it without asking for it, you will be helped (by divine support).
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6622) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1652c)</sup>

Note that this for a person who wants it because of lust for power. There are situations when seeking such positions can be permissible or even obligatory, which is when a person knows that he can bring reform and there is no other person present who is competent and righteous - as evidenced by the [Quran 12:55](https://quran.com/12/55?translations=20)